# If a photographer wants to sell product image of a shampoo bottle, does he need to take permission from shampoo brand?

Tags: copyright, stock-images, photography

I want to understand the copyright situation when it comes to selling stock images of products. Are they supposed to be editorial use only? Let's say if there is an image of a particular brand shampoo, a photographer wants to sell it. Does he have to take permission from the shampoo brand? ( that shapoo was bought by him for example )

Comment: If their logo is not visible then no. Physicalbobjects do not have copyright but their design may have been patented. But to answer we need your locale

Comment: This is a really good question. Ex: You're designing a sales flyer for a mom and pop shop. Do you need to ask permission from Tide to display it will be half off this week?

Comment: A good question indeed. How are you supposed to sell second hand merchandises if you are not allowed to take pictures of what you want to sell?

Answer (score 1):

> Does he have to take permission from the shampoo brand?

**Yes**.
He'll need to acquire permission from the respective owners. Generally, this type of signed permission is called **Property Release**.

### What types of subjects require a property release?

As [Adobe Stock](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/stock/contributor/help/property-release.html) says:

- Famous landmarks, historic locations, and modern architecture
- Copyrighted works like art, books, maps, fictional characters
- Identifiable exterior or interior of private homes and buildings
- Distinctive product shapes like toys, **bottles**, luxury furniture, vehicles, aeroplanes
- Unique animals, such as race horses, famous pets, certain zoo animals
- Properties with photography policies, which may include stadiums, museums, concert venues, amusement parks

You can also read [What types of subjects require a property release? - Shutterstock](https://www.shutterstock.com/contributorsupport/articles/kbat02/000006642)

> Are they supposed to be editorial use only?

If the photographer **couldn't acquire the release**, then he is supposed to sell it under **Editorial Use Only**.

### Sources & Guidelines

- [What Is a Property Release? - Lifewire](https://www.lifewire.com/property-release-for-design-1078153)
- [Photography StackExchange](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/property-release)
- [Property and model releases explained - Alamy](https://www.alamy.com/help/what-is-model-release-property-release.aspx)
- [Does your content have model/property releases? - Shutterstock](https://www.shutterstock.com/support/article/Do-your-images-have-model-releases)
- [Property release requirements - Adobe Stock](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/stock/contributor/help/property-release.html)
- [Model & Property Releases - Getty Images](https://contributors.gettyimages.com/article_public.aspx?article_id=3069)

**n.b.** *If you're selling stock photos online, make sure to check their help articles and resources. Please note that I'm not a lawyer. I answered this based on the information found on the internet.*

Answer (score 0):

Depends in the country you want to use your photo and on the specific Shampoo brand.
Generally speaking, I wouldn’t use it since in most countries and most brands the answer will be No.

Comment: Do you have any citations? I find it hard to believe you can't advertise in a flyer generic or name brand items in a mom and pop shop type scenario. I'm not a lawyer but this answer needs more